# Can I charge an iPad from a 14 volt cigarette lighter socket?

Tags: ipad, charging

I have a small airplane which provides 14V (volts) through a cigarette lighter socket. Can I use this to charge an iPad?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Unfortunately I've had to close your question. This is due to the fact that it is too broad and, to a lesser extent, primarily opinion-based. It may be useful for you to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you can reword your question to avoid the pitfalls explained on that page, then we can consider reopening your question. Regardless, I hope you find the time to explore the site as it does provide a wealth of information and has an active community willing to help when you run into problems.

Comment: Can you add some details about the kind of charger you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, but you have to check the input range of the adapter.**

DC voltages in a car can vary between 10V (at rest) and 16V (charging).   Most USB chargers you buy can handle this variance.

However, there are some applications where the voltage can be (much) higher like aviation, trucking, and marine where the voltages can reach up to 24 volts.

This is where paying attention to the specifications and buying high quality is very important. Here are two high quality ones that I personally use

- [Scosche Dual ReVolt](https://www.scosche.com/consumer-tech/usb-car-charger-dual-port) - Up to 16V
- [Anker PowerDrive Speed 2 Ports](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/powerdrive-speed-2-ports/A2228011) - Up to 24V

I use the Scoshe mostly because it's low profile and I can close the ash tray door with it still plugged in (though it always gets "appropriated" by someone else).